# How do you check multiple value for the same row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have these four tables:

**quotes**

```
id | uid | tid | message | time
```

**quotes_rnd**

```
id | message
```

**users**

```
idu | username
```

**authors**

```
id | uid | name
```

I need to populate the `quotes` table so this is my procedure:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO quotes
(message)
SELECT message
FROM quotes_rnd ORDER BY RAND() limit 1;

UPDATE quotes SET tid = (
SELECT id FROM authors WHERE id>10 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)
WHERE tid = 0;

UPDATE quotes SET uid = (
SELECT idu FROM users WHERE idu BETWEEN 13 AND 63 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)
WHERE uid = 0;

END
```

**The problem**

```
UPDATE quotes SET uid = (
SELECT idu FROM users WHERE idu BETWEEN 13 AND 63 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)
WHERE uid = 0;
```

Before this query line, the `tid` value is already set, instead the `uid=0`.

How to `SET uid` only when `uid.tid` of all rows inside the table `quotes` is different from the one randomized here for the last row?

Comment: I may be wrong, but the data model seems flawed. `tid`is the authors' ID, yes? And an author is a user with a `uid`. So why are there two columns, `uid` and `tid`, in quotes? `tid` is the author, who is related to a user ID implicitely. But who is `uid`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Hi, yes `tid` is the author's ID, and the `uid` is from the `users` table, check the last query.

Comment: Yes, but who is this user? I understand that a quote has one author, but in your table a quote has additionally one user. Who is that person? What does that person have to do with the quote?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ok, users are the users registered into the website while authors are inserted by me. So basically `id` is the primary key, `uid` is the user id, `tid` is the author id, `message` is the `quotes_rnd` message and `time` is the timestamp.

Comment: Your answer is very technical. So you insert authors. These have a uid, so every author must be a registered user, right? Then someone enters quotes. Each quote has an author (tid), but it also has a user (uid). What I've been asking is: who is this user? Is it the user who inserted the quote? And as to the message: You store the messages twice, once in quotes, once in quotes_rnd? Shouldn't one of the two tables rather use the other table's ID, so as to point to the message?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `These have a uid, so every author must be a registered user, right?` No, Authors are inserted by admin and are not related with the `users`, users are related to the authors...`authors (uid)` and `quotes (uid)` are not linked, indeed are 2 separate and different things.

Comment: Okay, so you cannot explain what meaning the uid entries in authors and quotes have, but at least you can say that the two are unrelated. That doesn't seem to be a problem then (I said I may be wrong :-), though the duplicate message text still seems strange in this model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90520/discussion-between-simone-and-thorsten-kettner).

Comment: Now to your question: You insert a quotes record with a random message from quotes_rnd. All other fields are NULL. Then you update all records where tid = 0 with one random tid from authors. This seems to have nothing to do with the insert you just did, right? Then you update all records where uid = 0 with one random idu from users. Again this seems not to be related to the insert and updates you did before. So I simply fail to see what you actually want to do and what your question is. (I don't use the chat, because I think we don't have to talk about the datamodel anymore).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in the first step I insert a row (so the `quotes` table looks like this ex.  `id=36 | uid=0 | tid=0 | message=hello world | time=2015-06-23 18:14:04`). The next step is to `UPDATE` the `tid` value and after the `uid`

Comment: Oh, so there are triggers filling these values? You should have said this. Alright, so you expect only your last inserted record to still have `tid` and `uid` = 0, so it is actually the same record you work on. You update the `tid` and are fine with it. But you are not satisfied with your `uid` update, because you only want the value to change from 0 to *random* when the record's `tid` is unique in the table. Is this correct? (If the value stays 0, there will of course be two records with `uid`= 0 next time, etc.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner everything else you wrote is correct except this `because you only want the value to change from 0 to random when the record's tid is unique in the table` ...it's not that easy, I need to change the `uid` only when `uid.tid` (the combination of `uid` and `tid` in the same row) of last row (so the one we're currently updating) is unique in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear reader: The first two solutions fail with

> MySQL: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'upd' for update in FROM clause"

I keep them here, though, as to make the problem known. Please scroll down to "EDIT" to see my third solution, which is working and is the one that's been accepted :-)

<strike>You say you want to try once with a random user and stay with uid = 0 in case of  duplicate uid + tid. For this you'd use an UPDATE with a join:</strike>

```
UPDATE quotes upd 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT idu FROM users WHERE idu BETWEEN 13 AND 63 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) u
SET upd.uid = u.iud
WHERE upd.uid = 0
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  select *
  from quotes q
  where q.tid = upd.tid
  and q.uid = u.uid
);
```

If, however, you wanted to find a non-duplicating user as long as possible, you'd use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE quotes upd
SET uid = coalesce
(
  (
    SELECT idu 
    FROM users u
    WHERE idu BETWEEN 13 AND 63 
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
      select *
      from quotes q
      where q.tid = upd.tid
      and q.uid = u.uid
    )
    ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
  ), 0
)
WHERE uid = 0;
```

The difference: You take all non-duplicating users into account. As long as there is at least one, you will update. Whereas with the first update statement, you'd just try just one random user, and either it's a non-duplicationg one then you'd update, else not.

EDIT: I am not fluent in MySQL yet, so I don't know how to overcome the MySQL limitation here quickly. If, however, you like the idea behind the second approach, then you might even want to strive to get tid/uid pairs as long as possible, i.e. don't update with a used-up tid when there are still tid/uid pairs for other tids available. You could do this all on insert:

```
INSERT INTO quotes (message, tid, uid)
SELECT q.message, a.id, coalesce(u.idu,0)
FROM quotes_rnd q
JOIN authors a ON a.id > 10 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.idu BETWEEN 13 AND 63
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    select *
    from quotes q
    where q.tid = a.id
    and q.uid = u.idu
  )
ORDER BY (u.idu IS NULL), rand() LIMIT 1;
```

(This is kind of cross-joining in order to find all possible pairs, so it might be slow on large tables.)

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b756b/1.

Comment: I tried the second option and I got this error message: `MySQL: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'upd' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Sorry, I don't know how to quickly solve this and don't have much time right now. (One could post this as a separate question of course.) But I've added an alternative.

Comment: thanks, the last solution has solved my problem...please edit or delete the first option, it doesn't work (same problem as before)

Comment: Gosh, I'm glad at least the third query helped you :-) I've edited my answer such as to show that the first two methods both don't work. Sorry for having posted those untested update Statements; I don't use MySQL, so I just didn't know about this #1093 restriction.